# Silenting the noise down, after recording

Tags: noise, noise-cancelling, adobe-audition, adobe, silence

I have a fairly quiet studio to record vocals. However, when I record, the noise of the required cooling fans get in the way! The selected area of the wave in the picture is the low-noise I want to get rid of, and it seems to have a detectable volume threshold!

[image]

I know that in Adobe Audition, I can impose the "Silent" effect, but it's tedious and seems way unprofessional! So, how may I efficiently "hush" the unavoidable noise after recording?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at "noise gating".  But the combination of "recording studio" and "noise of the required cooling fans" does not make sense.  Either you need to turn off the fans when recording or you need to shield off the noise with appropriate measures.  Anything else is severely restricting the SNR ratios you can hope to achieve when recording.

Comment: It's a home studio, the cooling fan is under my laptop and makes some noises! I need a way to get rid of this noise after recording with a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to get rid of laptop cooling noises when recording is to put the laptop and audio interface in a different room.  That's what stage boxes are for.  You can use a KVM extension to get working silent keyboard/video/mouse without fan at your recording site, or you can use something like a nanoKONTROL (or similar device) with a USB extension cord (USB extension cord to soundcard is not a good idea since an extension cord is usually a hub and may cause dropouts) to control your DAW.

But controlling your recording is usually not even necessary: you can just record everything and sort out the material you want afterwards: audio recording capacity should be easy to supply in sufficient amounts.  Of course, when you do that, invest the first few minutes for a check: nothing more annoying to record a few hours and find that no recording was running or everything is distorted.

Answer (score 1):

Surprised nobody here has mentioned actual denoising algorithms. If you can't remove the source of the noise or can't re-record what you already have, look into effects such as izotope rx and edison. Even Audacity, which is free, has a noise reduction algorithm.

You've highlighted a section of the pure noise, which is what is fed to the algorithm as an example of the noise it needs to remove. Try to leave a few seconds of just the noise in the beginning or end of your recording, so that the program can perform a more accurate analysis. If the noise texture evolves throughout, leave several pauses.

In the software you need to find a noise cancelling effect that requires a "noise profile". Select the pauses as the noise profile and tweak it from that point on.